# How to be sure whether std::strtof succeeded or failed?

Tags: c++, std

If `strtof` can't convert the string, it returns 0.0.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/ doesn't say what the function does to `endptr`in case the conversion doesn't succeed (is the behavior undefined in that case?)

How can I distinguish between successful conversion from a string that parses to 0 and a failed conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) for `float strtof(const char* str, char** str_end)`:

> If no conversion can be performed, ​0​ is returned and `*str_end` is set to `str`.

So you may just check if `*str_end == str`, since in any other case (e.g. reading a literal 0) `*str_end` will have to have advanced at least one character.